# Everytime I call a method I want the value to be decreased by 1

Tags: python

Is there a way I can decrease the value by 1 every time I call the method.

The code I tried is

```
Class Testing:
    max_count = 5
    def update_count(self, reducebyone):
        actual_count = max_count
        updated_count = actual_count - reducebyone
        resetcount = updated_count
        print(actual_count)
        print(updated_count)
        print(resetcount)

obj = Testing()
obj.update_count(1)
obj.update_count(1)
```

The result im expecting is when the method called first time I expect the O/P to be :
5
4
4
And second time when the method is called I expect the O/P to be :
4
3
3
Can anyone help in this.

Answer (score 1):

All your variables are local to the method. You will need to store the `count` state in the class or the instance. The way you invoke the method indicates you are after the latter:

```
class Testing:
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 5

    def update_count(self, reducebyone):
        print(self.count)
        self.count -= reducebyone
        print(self.count)

>>> obj = Testing()
>>> obj.update_count(1)
5
4
>>> obj.update_count(1)
4
3
```

Comment: Works Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Is this is what you wanted? A loop I think would be better, but I don't know what are you trying to achieve.

```
class Testing:
    max_count = 5
    cur_count = max_count

    def update_count(self, reducebyone):
        self.cur_count -= reducebyone
        resetcount = self.cur_count
        print(self.max_count)
        print(self.cur_count)
        print(resetcount)

obj = Testing()
obj.update_count(1)
obj.update_count(1)
```

Output:

```
5
4
4
5
3
3
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are plenty of ways to achieve this !

The easiest one would be to add `self.max_count = updated_count` after you compute updated_count. Also you need to access to `max_count` always using `self.max_count`